# EF4 Cascading Left Outer Joins Null Exception

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have this query

```
Select p.Name,p.Street from person p
left join address a on a.address_id = p.address_id
left join Order o on o.order_id = a.order_id
```

But when i try to convert it into LINQ query,

```
var q = from p in Entities.Person 
        from a in Entities.Address.Where(a=>a.address_id == p.address_id).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from o in Entities.Order.Where (o=>o.order_id== a.order_Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I am getting a Null exception since for some combination of address_ids there are no addresses and it blows up in o=>o.order_id== a.order_Id clause(since a is null).

Please let me know how to do multiple left joins in EF 4, the correct way !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have modeled correctly you do not need to explicitly do left outer joins.

```
Select p.Name, a.Street from person p
left join address a on a.address_id = p.address_id
left join Order o on o.order_id = a.order_id
```

The above query can be converted as follows

```
var projection = Entities.Person.Select(p => new {p.Name, p.Address.Street});
```

EF will automatically add the joins to retrieve the fields.

You can manually do the joins as follows

```
 var projection = from p in Entities.Person
        join a in Entities.Address on p.address_id equals a.address_id into outer
        from a in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {p.Name, a.Street};
```

Comment: Thanks ! So are you saying there is no way to code the way i did to achieve this goal ?Bcos you can see i need to do a left join with Order table too with address table.

Comment: @user636525 added an example of doing outer join manually. It requires more key strokes to achieve the same thing!!